# Neo4j: "Failed to rotate logs exception" at shutdown

Tags: java, neo4j, shutdown

I have a neo4j 3.2.1 multi-labeled multi-properties graph database which has 4M nodes, 15M edges, and 4.8M distinct labels with ~6GB size on the disk.

I've imported the dataset using "neo4j-import" tool using a linux machine.

I can open the dataset, traverse the nodes, edges, and their descriptions well using the Java API. However, once I want to shut it down, it takes a lot of time and finally, it gives me the following log file error:

```html
2017-08-04 07:07:38.189+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.f.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory] Shutdown started
2017-08-04 07:07:38.190+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.f.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory] Database is now unavailable
2017-08-04 07:07:38.198+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.t.l.c.CheckPointerImpl] Check Pointing triggered by database shutdown [5399]:  Starting check pointing...
2017-08-04 07:07:38.198+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.t.l.c.CheckPointerImpl] Check Pointing triggered by database shutdown [5399]:  Starting store flush...
2017-08-04 07:23:35.022+0000 ERROR [o.n.k.i.t.l.c.CheckPointerImpl] Error performing check point Failed to rotate logs. Expected version: 5399, actual version: 5274, wait timeout (ms): 956815
org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.kvstore.RotationTimeoutException: Failed to rotate logs. Expected version: 5399, actual version: 5274, wait timeout (ms): 956815
 at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.kvstore.RotationState$Rotation.rotate(RotationState.java:79)
 at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.kvstore.RotationState$Rotation.rotate(RotationState.java:52)
 at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.kvstore.AbstractKeyValueStore$RotationTask.rotate(AbstractKeyValueStore.java:311)
 at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.kvstore.AbstractKeyValueStore$RotationTask.rotate(AbstractKeyValueStore.java:288)
 at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.counts.CountsTracker.rotate(CountsTracker.java:154)
 at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.NeoStores.flush(NeoStores.java:242)
 at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.storageengine.impl.recordstorage.RecordStorageEngine.flushAndForce(RecordStorageEngine.java:480)
 at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.log.checkpoint.CheckPointerImpl.doCheckPoint(CheckPointerImpl.java:160)
 at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.log.checkpoint.CheckPointerImpl.forceCheckPoint(CheckPointerImpl.java:88)
 at org.neo4j.kernel.NeoStoreDataSource$3.shutdown(NeoStoreDataSource.java:794)
 at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.shutdown(LifeSupport.java:489)
 at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.shutdown(LifeSupport.java:206)
 at org.neo4j.kernel.NeoStoreDataSource.stop(NeoStoreDataSource.java:766)
 at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.stop(LifeSupport.java:458)
 at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.stopInstances(LifeSupport.java:161)
 at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.stop(LifeSupport.java:143)
 at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.state.DataSourceManager.stop(DataSourceManager.java:120)
 at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.stop(LifeSupport.java:458)
 at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.stopInstances(LifeSupport.java:161)
 at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.stop(LifeSupport.java:143)
 at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.shutdown(LifeSupport.java:191)
 at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.ClassicCoreSPI.shutdown(ClassicCoreSPI.java:159)
 at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacade.shutdown(GraphDatabaseFacade.java:366)
 at experiment.caseStudy.TestDatasetHealth.run(TestDatasetHealth.java:70)
 at experiment.caseStudy.TestDatasetHealth.main(TestDatasetHealth.java:29)
2017-08-04 07:23:35.665+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] --- STOPPING diagnostics START ---
2017-08-04 07:23:35.666+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] --- STOPPING diagnostics END ---
```

In the Java itself, I get the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.NeoStoreDataSource$3@3101ffd3' failed to transition from stopped to shutting_down. Please see the attached cause exception "Failed to rotate logs. Expected version: 5399, actual version: 5274, wait timeout (ms): 956815".
at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.shutdown(LifeSupport.java:497)
at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.shutdown(LifeSupport.java:206)
at org.neo4j.kernel.NeoStoreDataSource.stop(NeoStoreDataSource.java:766)
at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.stop(LifeSupport.java:458)
at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.stopInstances(LifeSupport.java:161)
at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.stop(LifeSupport.java:143)
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.state.DataSourceManager.stop(DataSourceManager.java:120)
at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.stop(LifeSupport.java:458)
at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.stopInstances(LifeSupport.java:161)
at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.stop(LifeSupport.java:143)
at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.shutdown(LifeSupport.java:191)
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.ClassicCoreSPI.shutdown(ClassicCoreSPI.java:159)
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacade.shutdown(GraphDatabaseFacade.java:366)
at experiment.caseStudy.TestDatasetHealth.run(TestDatasetHealth.java:70)
at experiment.caseStudy.TestDatasetHealth.main(TestDatasetHealth.java:29)
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.kvstore.RotationTimeoutException: Failed to rotate logs. Expected version: 5399, actual version: 5274, wait timeout (ms): 956815
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.kvstore.RotationState$Rotation.rotate(RotationState.java:79)
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.kvstore.RotationState$Rotation.rotate(RotationState.java:52)
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.kvstore.AbstractKeyValueStore$RotationTask.rotate(AbstractKeyValueStore.java:311)
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.kvstore.AbstractKeyValueStore$RotationTask.rotate(AbstractKeyValueStore.java:288)
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.counts.CountsTracker.rotate(CountsTracker.java:154)
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.NeoStores.flush(NeoStores.java:242)
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.storageengine.impl.recordstorage.RecordStorageEngine.flushAndForce(RecordStorageEngine.java:480)
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.log.checkpoint.CheckPointerImpl.doCheckPoint(CheckPointerImpl.java:160)
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.log.checkpoint.CheckPointerImpl.forceCheckPoint(CheckPointerImpl.java:88)
at org.neo4j.kernel.NeoStoreDataSource$3.shutdown(NeoStoreDataSource.java:794)
at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.shutdown(LifeSupport.java:489)
```

In fact, in the Java program, I just read the information and do not write anything on the dataset.

Furthermore, to open the database using the following line of code, it takes 80 seconds on a 3.1GHz Core i7 MacBook with 16GB of Ram with 10GB of JVM arguments.
Is it normal to take this much of time for a dataset with the mentioned size?

```
GraphDatabaseService dataGraph = new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabase(storeDir);
```

Could you please guide me how can I repair the dataset to be easily shut down?

Comment: This may be beside the point, but you've created the database with neo4j-import (which is now replaced by neo4j-admin import btw) and then open it embedded in an application. Does your application use the same OS user as the neo4j-import did ?

Comment: To check this, I've run the code over the system that I've imported the dataset with. The error still the same. My main question is how can I repair it if I'm fine with the current saved data there.